Chinese Hawthorn (Crataegus pinnatifida) Hardiness?
I'm wondering how well Chinese Hawthorn will grow in Auckland, New Zealand?
There are 1 or 2 sellers online in Auckland selling this plant, but most sellers appear to be in the much colder South Island.
According to https://plants.ces.ncsu.edu/plants/crataegus-pinnatifida/ it may be marginal as at a guess we fall between zone 9b and 10 on the USDA hardiness zone.   We are also at about 60 meters above see level (a few km's from the sea - Auckland can get fairly humid), and I get the impression that this plant is typically found in higher altitudes?   On the flip side, we do live rurally, and it gets quite a bit colder here then in other parts of Auckland - indeed frost is rare in suburbia but frost is common here in Winter on cloudless nights.
I don't know the chill hours that Chinese Hawthorn needs, but our area is marginal for growing [Hass] Avocado's in sheltered areas and is OK for Citrus fruit.  We also have quite a few stone fruit growing - so I guess this somewhat talks to the climate/environment.
Does anyone know what the likelyhood of successfully growing this tree [for its fruit] might be?

Do note low temp ratings are rather conservative. My lemon and tomatoes seem to endure the unthinkable 1°C as long as the plants are mature and happy. And not that cold for long.

@Vorac thank you for your comment.  I confirm I'm worried about it being to warm - not to cold for this plant.
